# set public/private on template function for some certain template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to make a certain template function have 2 accessibility level for some certain template parameter?  (via splitting into 2 functions?)

```
class B{
    enum ENU{
        T0,T1,T2   
    }
    template<ENU T=T0> someType f(){  ... } //want T1,T2 = public,  T0 = private
};
```

Current usage (the solution should not change it):-

```
B b;
int aa=b.f<T0>(); //should fail
std::string bb=b.f<T1>();// should ok
```

**Edit:** B has a lot of functions like this.

---

---

Here is the full code (just in case someone want to edit or use) https://ideone.com/ryNCml.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt what you are trying to do is possible, as specializing functions on a value ain't allowed in C++.

Though if you don't need enumerations, you could write something similar:

```
class B {
public:
     struct T0{};
     struct T1{};
     struct T2{};
     template<typename T> void f(T, ...) {
          static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, T1> || std::is_same_v<T, T2>); 
     }
private:
     void f(T0, ...) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    B b{};
    b.f(T1{}); // Should compile
    b.f(T0{}); // Should not compile
}
```

If you would use the same function implementation, you can either forward this to a common method, or simply put `T0` private.

Alternatively, you could make use of a proxy object which could convert the value, though I'm not sure if this is standard C++ of an extension of the compiler I'm familiar with:

```
class B {
public:
    enum class T { //< Strong typed!
        T0,
        T1,
        T2
    }
    template <T t>
    struct TWrapper {};

    template <T ActualT>
    void f(..., TWrapper<ActualT> tw = TWrapper<ActualT>{}); 
private:
    template <>
    struct TWrapper<T0> {};
}
```

Comment: Cool! I was still struggling to get the member template function specialization managed.

Comment: I test, it works... but not cute as template, ... thank! (upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand, you want to forbid the use of `T0` as a template parameter while invoking member method `f`.
To do that, you can use either `std::enable_if` or a `static_assert`.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

class B {
public:
    enum ENU { T0,T1,T2 };

    template<ENU T>
    std::enable_if_t<(T==T1||T==T2),int>
    f() { return 42; }

    template<ENU T>
    int g(){
        static_assert(T==T1||T==T2, "not allowed");
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f<B::T1>();
    // It doesn't work
    //b.f<B::T0>();
    b.g<B::T1>();
    // It doesn't work
    //b.g<B::T0>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to support only a finite set of template arguments, I would write three functions which are not template functions, and give them the right visibility. Then make them delegate to a private template function which does the work.   This would look like:

```
class B{
public:
    enum ENU{
        T0,T1,T2   
    }
private:
    template<ENU T=T0> int f(){ 
          std::cout<<"In enum "<<T<<std::endl;
          return 0;
    }

protected:
    someType fT0() { return f<T0>(); }
public:
    someType fT1() { return f<T1>(); }
    someType fT2() { return f<T2>(); }

};
```

Contrary to your requirements, the usage changes - but this is often the simplest approach:

```
B b;
int aa=b.fT0(); // fails
int bb=b.fT1();// ok
```

Alternatively, you can make the template be public, but give it a dummy argument (with a default), and make the type of the dummy argument depend on the template parameter (via traits). If the type of the dummy is a private class, the template will only be callable by a member.

```
template <ENU T>
struct protection_traits;

class B{
friend class protection_traits<T0>; // So it has access to Protected.
protected:
    struct Protected{};
public:
    struct Public{};

    enum ENU{
        T0,T1,T2   
    }
    template<ENU T=T0> int f( typename protection_traits<T>::type = {})
      { std::cout<<"In enum "<<T<<std::endl; }
};

template <ENU T>
struct protection_traits 
{
    typedef B::Public type;   // Default to public
};
template<>
struct protection_traits<T0> 
{ 
    typedef B::Protected type;  // But T0 uses Protected
};
```

Usage:

```
B b;
int aa=b.f<T0>(); // fails (no access to B::Protected)
int bb=b.f<T1>(); // ok
```

Note: This latter solution hasn't been fed to a compiler.  There will be typos.

Comment: I am losing track at "make the type of the dummy argument depend on the template parameter (via traits)", can you edit my full code (I edited question) OR provide some examples?

Comment: He means he wants you to pass as an argument a certain trait that makes the class unique. For example if you have a car class and you want to make it unique, make an interface of it, "IIndentifier", and use that as your template schema (The dummy argument will get an IIdentifier as its object)

Comment: Yes......  I can interpret that but only vaguely (that it helps template deduction) .... don't know how to transform into code....  I am just a beginner for C++...  trait? schema? what are those? all confuse me   .... can you look into the full code? I think I already use that technique.

Comment: That interface is a trait -> a template of itself, that can be passed to the original template.

Comment: You can search it online, its called template traits